# get all dates in year two under weeks interval

Tags: php, date

I need to get all days under two weeks interval as example

```
2019-01-01 t0  2019-01-14
2019-01-15  to 2019-01-29
2019-01-30 to  2019-02-14
.........................
.........................
...............
2019-12-xx to  2019-12-31
```

I need achieve it with php
I haven't idea how to get all days in year such a manner
can you suggest any how I achieve this

Comment: What is the data source? And have you tried resolving this yourself before posting?

Comment: yes I tryied .need achieve with php only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can find interval in php. I have done it in form of array but you can do in in form of string. Find my below code

```
<?php 

function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+15 day', $format = 'Y/m/d' ) {

    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime( $first );
    $last = strtotime( $last );

    while( $current <= $last ) {
        $data = [];
        $data['start'] = date( $format, $current );
        $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
        $data['end'] =date( $format, $current );
        $dates[] = $data; 
        if ($current >= $last) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $dates;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r( dateRange( '2010/01/01', '2010/05/31') );
```

Let me know if you face any issues.Enjoy it.